# Python selenium driver run not as a automated test softeware

Tags: python, selenium

So im trying to make a program in python using selenium that automatically logs me into my extensions, however im not being allowed to log into these extensions due to it being on a automated test software, that being the chromedriver.exe. I was wondering if there a driver that isnt register as a automated test software but as a normal user would work around this or if there are any work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

One way is, use a data directory for your driver. Before running chrome with selenium, you can run chrome with a data directory for a specific path. e.g.:

```
# run_brower.py
import os
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
os.system(f"start \"\" \"{chrome_path}\" --user-data-dir=\"%cd%\cd\" --window-position=0,0")
```

Then manually add extensions, then log into your extensions and close the chrome.
After that your sessions are saved in that "data directory", so run selenium by giving an argument for the same directory:

```
# main.py
from pathlib import Path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
BASE_DIR = Path(__name__).absolute().parent
options = Options()
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={BASE_DIR / 'cd'}")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# ...
```